# Prove convergence of $\langle T,\phi \rangle=e\iint_{y>x^{2}+x}x\phi (x,y)\, dx\,dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, distribution-theory

I'm going to prove convergence of this application :

$$\phi \in D(\mathbb{R^{2}})$$

$$\langle T,\phi \rangle=\iint_{y>x^{2}+x}x\phi (x,y)\, dx\,dy$$

My try: $\phi \in D(\mathbb{R^{2}})$, so there exists $r>0$ such that $\operatorname{supp}\phi \subset\mathrm C(O,r)\subset\mathbb{R^{2}}$, where
$\mathrm C$ is a circle.

Then: $r>x>-r$ and $x+x^{2}<y<r$, so:

$$\begin{split}
\langle T,\phi \rangle &=\int_{[-r,r]}\int_{[x+x^2,r]}x\phi (x,y)\ dydx \\
&≤\sup_{\mathrm C} \int_{[-r,r]}\int_{[x+x^2,r]}x\ dydx \\
&=\sup_{\mathrm C} \int_{[-r,r]}|(rx-x^{2}-x^{3})|\ dx \\
&=r^{2}\sup_{\mathrm C}<\infty
\end{split}$$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes. More obvious : $\langle T,\phi\rangle  \le \langle |x|,|\phi| \rangle\le \langle  r,|\phi|\rangle\le \|\phi\|_\infty \pi r^2$ where $\phi$ is supported on $|x|<r$. Note this proves the map is continuous for the test function topology.

Comment: @reuns How the first inequality $≤$

Comment: @reuns how you find $π^{2}$ ??